# Find file name not present in a directory

Tags: c#

I have list if files names(not paths) in a `List<string>`. I have to find a `List<string>` of files that are NOT present in a directory.

Right now I am iterating the files one by one and checking each one of them to all files in the folder.

Is there any LINQ way of achiving the same thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how many names you have in your list (and how many files are in the destination), you may find that the iterative approach is still the most efficient (but with some LINQ enhancements):

```
var missingFiles = names.Where(x => !File.Exists(x));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) like:

```
List<string> compareList = new List<string>();
//.... items in the list

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
var fileArray = di.GetFiles().Select(r => r.Name).ToArray();

var filesNotPresent = compareList.Except(fileArray);
```